# How can I set page dimensions for a CWEB document?

Tags: paper-size, cweb

I have a CWEB file and I want to change the page dimensions. I know how to do this in a plain TeX document, and it always worked fine for me. If I do the same (changing hsize, the offsets, etc.) in the CWEB file, I get completely screwed up margins and placement.

I want to have output in A4 paper. The final page dimensions are set by my pdftex to A4, so that is not the problem. The problem is rather that CWEB is made for letter paper output, so the copy is not centered, for instance.

I tried to look for a solution in Knuth's Stanford Graphbase, since it is a bunch of CWEB programs published in book format, so he must have done something to change page dimensions. The sources he makes available on the internet, however, are made for letter output, so they are of no help. Any ideas?

So far, I added the following code to the beginning of the CWEB file (this code works in a plain TeX file by the way):

```
\newdimen\pagewidth   \pagewidth=210mm
\newdimen\pageheight  \pageheight=297mm

\hsize=13cm

\hoffset=\pagewidth
\advance\hoffset by-\hsize
\hoffset=.5\hoffset
\advance\hoffset by-1in

\voffset=\pageheight
\advance\voffset by-\vsize
\voffset=0.5\voffset
\advance\voffset by-1in
```

Comment: Show us the code you have got so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the CWEB manual (which you can open by invoking `texdoc cweb` which opens a DVI file, or [read as PDF online](http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/doc/cwebman.pdf#page=26)), in **Appendix C: How to use CWEB macros** (page 25), point 4.

The trick is that after setting any of `\pagewidth` (default 6.5in), `\pageheight` (default 8.7in) or `\fullpageheight` (default 9in), you need to say `\setpage`:

> If you change any of these quantities, you should call the macro
>   \setpage immediately after making the change.

---

**Example**: If you download [lp.w](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/lp.w) from Knuth's [downloadable programs page](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs.html), and run `cweave lp.w`, you get an `lp.tex`, which processed with `tex lp.tex` (or `pdftex lp.tex`) gives the following as the first page:

[image: lp-default]

If you change the top of `lp.tex` from

```
\input cwebmac
\datethis
```

to

```
\input cwebmac
\pagewidth=3.25in % The default is 6.5in
\pageheight=4.35in % The default is 8.7in
\fullpageheight=4.5in % The default is 9in
\setpage
\datethis
```

(halving everything), then (if you don't change the pdf paper size) you get the following:

[image: lp-halved]

---

For A4 paper specifically, if you want to keep the same margin as with letter paper (which may not make much sense, but is one option), then you can change the `\input cwebmac` at the top of the `.tex` file to (if you're using `pdftex`):

```
\input cwebmac
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\pdfpageheight=297mm
\pagewidth= 159.2mm % The default is 6.5in for 8.5in width, so for A4 this is 210mm - 2in
\pageheight=238.58mm % The default is 8.7in for 11in height, so for A4 this is 297mm - 2.3in
\fullpageheight=246.2mm % The default is 9in for 11in height, so for A4 this is 297mm - 2in
\setpage
```

If you want to keep the layout (the text width, the line breaks, etc.) the same as for letter paper but instead squeeze and center that onto A4 paper (as suggested in Igor's answer), then of course what you need to do is nothing specific to `cwebmac` and you can use the same block of code everywhere: you can simply adjust `\pdfhorigin`: the default is `1in` (=(8.5in - 6.5in)/2). Just add this at the top of your file and don't change anything else:

```
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\pdfpageheight=297mm
\pdfhorigin=\dimexpr (210mm-6.5in)/2
\pdfvorigin=\dimexpr (297mm-9in)/2
```